# Parse configuration to Junit5 Tests

Tags: java, junit, junit5

My tests require the extraction of data from a file.
I want to pass the location of the file together with some other parameters to the Junit tests.

Can this be done via commandline arguments? If not, what is the recommended way to do that?
Creating a configuration file or environment variables?

Comment: How do get the file name into your production code? Why can’t you use the same mechanism for your test?

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended with junit to read variables out of the config and to use them for the tests, because then the tests are no longer based on the code but partly on your config.

You should rather hard code the variables. An example from one of my projects:

```
  @Test
  public void testIfEmailValidatorReturnsCorrectValue() {
    Validators validator = Validators.getInstance();
    Assert.assertFalse(validator.isMail(""));
    Assert.assertFalse(validator.isMail("test"));
    Assert.assertFalse(validator.isMail("test@mail"));
    Assert.assertFalse(validator.isMail("test@mail:de"));
    Assert.assertFalse(validator.isMail("test@test@mail.de"));
    Assert.assertFalse(validator.isMail("testmail.de"));
    Assert.assertFalse(validator.isMail("test@mail.d$e"));
    Assert.assertTrue(validator.isMail("test@mail.de"));
    Assert.assertTrue(validator.isMail("testASD01@Ma1l.com"));
    Assert.assertTrue(validator.isMail("testASD01@sub.Ma1l.com"));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :) This makes complete sense to me. Sadly, I am required to perform some very strange system test where only the output of the tool (in a file) is checked. So in the end, I need to provide the parameter option, whether it is recommended or not :(